# How to Get the @Configuration annotation capability in Spring2.5.1

Tags: spring

I need to load property file when context is loading.(constants.properties As per below example)  one of the keys in this property file pointing to another property file (for example privatedata.properties) which is not in the class path. I need to read properties of privatedata.properties file and inject to my bean. I can do this as below with the help of @Configuration annotation in spring 3.x. How would I get the same capability in Spring2.5.1 ?

**With Spring 3.x**

```
package com.snippets.enterprise;

**@Configuration**

@PropertySource("classpath:/constants.properties")

public class SpringConfig {    }

<context:component-scan base-package="com.snippets.enterprise"/>
 //constants.properties has a key called private.supportiveFile and that points to the   
 file in **non-class path**

 <context:property-placeholder location="file:${private.supportiveFile}" /> 

    <bean id="helloWorldBean"
    class="com.snippets.enterprise.services.HelloWorld">
     <property name="key" value="${keypath}" />
    </bean>

How can I get the same capability in Spring2.5.X. 

org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration is present from spring3.x onwards.
```

Comment: you've answered it yourself..

Comment: How to Get the @Configuration annotation capability in Spring2.5.1? org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration is not present in Spring2.5.X

Comment: I guess you should write a listener, when the applicationContext is start-up, you add the code to read the properties file that you want to add. More like this in SPring: ApplicationListener

Comment: May be refering to org.springframework.context.event.ContextStartedEvent which executes after complete loading context. So this does not address what is needed